# Weird situation in using a pointer as the argument for a C call Prolog Process

Tags: c, pointers, prolog, gnu-prolog

So basically my test is on 32bit x86 Linux, I use `GNU Prolog 1.4.4`

Here is the case, I have function `ptr.c` + `pro.pl` + `interface.c`

In the `ptr.c`, I use a wrapper to call a `Prolog` function in the `pro.pl`, then in the `pro.pl`, I use a prolog c interface to call a C function in `interface.c`, the argument is a **C pointer**.

I put some code here for each file:

**ptr.c**:

```
  int  C_wrapper_foo(int * e)                        
  {
    int  return_value; 

    int func;
    PlTerm arg[2];    //  function variable + return value insert
    PlBool res;

    func = Pl_Find_Atom("foo"); // function name insert

    Pl_Query_Begin(PL_FALSE);

    printf("%p\n", e);
    arg[0] = Pl_Mk_Integer((unsigned int)e);   // See, here I put pointer e as an arg

    arg[1] = Pl_Mk_Variable();

    res = Pl_Query_Call(func, 2, arg);          // insert (variable+return value)

    return_value = Pl_Rd_Integer(arg[1]);        // insert ()

    Pl_Query_End(PL_KEEP_FOR_PROLOG);

    return return_value;

  }
```

See, I put pointer `e` as the argument into Prolog.

Then in the Prolog code:

```
:- foreign(foo_c_instr(+integer)).

foo(E, FOO_RET) :-

foo_c_instr_0(E).
```

This is just a call into c function `foo_c_instr` in `interface.c` file.

```
PlBool foo_c_instr(int * e)
{
    printf("%p\n", e);
   return PL_TRUE;
}
```

The weird thing is that:

for example, the value of pointer `e` in the original `ptr.c` file is **0xbf9d4e4c**, however, in the `interface.c` file, its value becomes **0xff9d4e4c**!!!

This is so weird and I have debugged it for quite a while, but I just don't know what is wrong...

The interface I use to pass the pointer argument is:

```
arg[0] = Pl_Mk_Integer((unsigned int)e);
```

I read the manual of [gnu-prolog](http://www.hep.by/gnu/gprolog/gprolog070.html#toc297), and tried

```
arg[0] = Pl_Mk_Positive((unsigned int)e);
arg[0] = Pl_Mk_Integer((int)e);
arg[0] = Pl_Mk_Positive((int)e);
```

but it just can't work....

Could anyone give some help?

Comment: Not quite the most inconsistent indentation ever, but getting there.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry what..? I am not a English native speaker and I just don't get your pointer... :(

Comment: @computereasy he was politely explaining that your C code indentation is poor, making the C code more difficult to read than it needs to be.

Comment: What happens if you do, `arg[0] = Pl_Mk_Positive((PlLong)e);`?

Comment: @lurker No it stills can not work.. I am thinking that, as int in `Prolog` is 31bit, and `0xb` is `1011` while `0xf` is `1111`, is it something related to the 31bits of a integer..?

Comment: @lurker Hello lurker, I find a way to solve it and have tested it on simple c code as well as md5sum... it seems work well, even though I don't know why.. I am writing a answer below

Comment: In GNU prolog I think an integer is only 28 bits (signed or unsigned). `X = 0xfffffff.` will unify `X` with the value, but `X = 0x1fffffff.` will generate an overflow error. When you move into C, you're back at 32 bits, sign extended.

Comment: @lurker, Hello lurker, I am still stucked in this 28bit problem somehow, I posted it in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191587/how-to-use-a-long-int-in-gnu-prolog), could you give me some help on it..? THank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is my ad-hoc solution:

In the `interface.c` function, I do this mask on the pointer:

```
PlBool foo_c_instr(int * e)
{
   e = (unsigned int)e&0xbfffffff;
   printf("%p\n", e);
   return PL_TRUE;
}
```

then it works fine...