# How to use a "long int" in GNU Prolog?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

So basically it seems that GNU Prolog use 28bit integer on my 32bit x86 Linux.

The code below can not be compiled:

```
foo(A) :-
   A0 is 0xdeadbeef,
   A1 is A0 >> 8,
   A2 is A0 >> 16,
   A3 is A0 >> 24.
```

Then I am confused with two typical situations below:

1. How to represent a `32bit` integer in GNU Prolog (like 0xdeadbeef)?  and pushing it further, how to represent a 64 bit integer ? On 64 bit x86 Linux, `long long` type in C has 64 bit.
2. When using GNU Prolog to call C, the interface defined in the [manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog068.html) has `integer`, `positive` and others.. then if I want to pass a `32bit` integer from Prolog to C, which type should I choose..? I found an ad-hoc solution and writing it in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132386/weird-situation-in-using-a-pointer-as-the-argument-for-a-c-call-prolog-process), is there any better solution?

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU Prolog uses bounded integers, whose bounds depend on the architecture (32/64 bits). You can know these limits with (on a 64 bits):

```
| ?- current_prolog_flag(min_integer,X).

X = -1152921504606846976

yes
| ?- current_prolog_flag(max_integer,X).

X = 1152921504606846975
```

yes

A workaround to store bigger integers is to spit them into 2 parts and for instance use a Prolog structure to record them.